# svg as cursor url value not getting applied

Tags: javascript, css

I want to use an `svg` for cursor icon when the required details matches

the svg i'm using (ik its png to upload here)
[image]

```
.apply-copy{
    cursor: url('./icons/apply-format.svg'),auto;
}
```

how i'm changing the cursor

```
document.querySelector('.ck-editor__editable').classList.add('apply-copy');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to apply the special cursor to the second `.item` class.

Your code maybe working.. but make sure that your image path is correct `url('./icons/apply-format.svg')`

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('item')[1].classList.add('cursor');
```

```css
.item{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 5px auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.cursor{
  cursor: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehitY.png'), auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="item">something</div>
<div class="item">something</div>
<div class="item">something</div>
```

Comment: Okay you're right there is already a class defined in other css file that's why it wasn't getting applied.